# How can I display the total number of circles detected in OpenCV? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to count the total circles detected, Please help. 
Here is the original image:
[image: Original]

and this is the processed image

[image: Processed]

and this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('rbc1.jpg',0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,5,
                        param1=118,param2=8,minRadius=0,maxRadius=7)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
# draw the outer circle
cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1)
# draw the center of the circle
cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),1)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the shape of the circles.

```
print(circles.shape)
```

The output was (1,109,3)

where 109 is the number of circles detected.